# Scheduler not firing

Tags: acumatica, schedule

I have a development instance on my laptop and for some reason I cannot get any Automation schedules to fire.  If I create a schedule, it looks ok and shows the appropriate next execution time, but it never changes.  What am I missing to enable the scheduler?

Comment: Did you restore a snapshot to your instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of support, I was able to resolve this.  We deleted the application from the configuration manager and recreated it.  The scheduler then started working.  There was nothing obviously wrong, but creating the new instance worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you restored a snapshot on your site, you will need to go to screen Automation Schedules screen (SM205030) and click on Initialize Scheduler action.

This action exists in order to prevent schedules to be run directly after restoring a backup of an environment.

This was done to prevent necessary actions from happening on a test environement, e.g. spamming customers email, uploading important files to file provider, etc.

This is why this button need to be manually clicked after restoring a backup.

Comment: That button is disabled.  What else do I need to check.  I did restore a snapshot from production to seed the instance.